# ODP.Net driver strange DataBinding Issue in Winforms

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, odp.net

What I'm experiencing is very strange.  I have a `Control` that binds with a `List<T>`.  This list contains `object`s `Obj`. `Obj` is very basically defined right now:

```
public class Obj
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int ID {get;set;}
}
```

The problem code is this:

```
                try
                {
                    //this next line *always* throws 
                    //ORA-0933: SQL Command not properly ended                
                    this.rddlControl.DataSource = People.List(load);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    throw;
                }
```

This would be straightforward if `People.List(Obj filterObj)` was just an alias for a database search, but it isn't.  Naturally, I have stepped through the code and discovered the bit that's driving me crazy; `People.List` is successfully building its List and returns it with no errors.   Just to be sure, I tried declaring a second List initialized with a new List:

```
List<Obj> myList = new List<Obj>();
myList = People.List(load);
this.rddlControl.DataSource = myList;
```

and even

```
List<Obj> myList = new List<Obj>();     
myList = People.List(load);
List<Obj> anotherList = new List<Obj>();
anotherList.AddRange(myList.ToArray());
this.rddlControl.DataSource = anotherList;
```

*`People.List`consistently returns a List.  The error only occurs when assigning the datasource.*  I have no idea what I must be missing; there are no `nulls` in the list, no `nulls` in any `Property`of its `ItemArray` contents.  I've cleaned and built twice and even cleared out built versions using Windows Explorer once just to make sure VS's debugger isn't highlighting the wrong line.  Even the function building the objects that go in the List itself uses a stored procedure that is currently being used in a production environment with no errors, and looking at the `string` version of the calls involved there's no malformed `SQL` or stray semicolons or anything.  Can anyone tell me why in the world I'd get an error from the database at this binding step?

Comment: What version of ODP.NET are you using? Managed or unmanaged? I would try this with the latest version if you are not. If you are using ODP.NET managed driver, you can get it here: https://www.nuget.org/profiles/Oracle

Comment: I'm using Managed, version 4.112.4.0.  Unfortunately, I *have* to use this version, as the Oracle Client used on the machines where this will be is not the newest (a constraint from a unique configuration of 3rd party sales management software).  I did try the latest on a test app, but the app threw fits about the version of Oracle Client.  Upgrading there won't be an option until that 3rd party software gets an update.

Comment: I was just suggesting that you test with the latest nuget version so you can determine if this was a bug that's been fixed.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines, but it persisted when I tried in an environment with a recent Oracle Client version installed last night.  I think it may be something about the Telerik control that is, instead of actually binding to the object list, instead reconstructing the objects (which could form a query like `"Select x, y from Table where thingy = "` and break).   I've contacted Telerik.   In the meantime, I wrapped it in a try-catch and the catch uses a loop-and-add method if binding fails.  Interestingly, the data does bind when the error is thrown if the code is allowed to continue.